# How to select the Xcode version?

Tags: iphone

I have installed two versions of xcode on my system at different locations. How do I open my application in a particular version?

Answer (score 1):

Just open that xcode version that you want to use and make application in that....

Answer (score 1):

You decide which version you are going to use at the time you launch Xcode - either you launch 3.2.5 or you launch 4.0. You can not change the version of Xcode itself.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the `.xcodeproj` file-> `Open With` -> `Other...` -> navigate to the version of Xcode which you want (if you want check the flag "`Always open with`").