# How to select the xcode version from two different versions?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to select the Xcode version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977078/how-to-select-the-xcode-version)

In my mac i installed two different versions of xcode in two different locations.They are Xcode 3.2.5 and Xcode 4.0.At teh time of running the application if you want to change the version then how do you change that version?